# Stopping destructor being called

Tags: c++

I have a class on which I am overloading new and delete (these fetch and return memory from and to a memory pool). What's frustrating me is that the class on which I have overloaded still has it's destructor called before the delete overloaded function get's called. How can I stop this?

```
class Message
{
    ~Message() { ... }

    void* operator new(std::size_t sz) { ... }
    void operator delete(void* ptr) { ... }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Am correct in thinking that the members of the class will be destructed but the memory won't be freed by the destructors; the delete function owns this responsiblity in which case I can stop the memory from being deallocated?

**OUTCOME:**
Penny dropped that the allocation/deallocation of memory and construction/destruction are separate items. I now have empty destructors and overloaded new/delete.

Comment: I don't know why that is frustrating; C++ is very logical in this regard. Leave an empty destructor if you don't need it to do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Destruction and de-allocation are two orthogonal things, one should not inhibit the other. What would you do with instances of your class that were created on the stack? Not cleanup their resources? You are trying to break a very useful concept of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can prevent the destructor from being called, and I'm not sure why you would want to. The object must be destroyed before the memory is freed - if the superclass allocated some resources, its destructor must free them before the object's memory is free'd.

Edit after your edit: Yes, the destructors clean up anything they allocated but don't deallocate the object's memory. The `delete` method you're writing does that.

BTW, nice name. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about (a) grabbing memory from a specific pool and (b) controlling when destructors are called one option is [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.14):

```
void* raw = allocate(sizeof(Foo));  // line 1
Foo* p = new(raw) Foo();            // line 2

p->~Foo();   // explicitely call destructor
```

(code taken from above link to C++ FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, yes constructors and destructors are called whether you overload new/delete or not.

Answering a question that you didn't ask, whether it's a good solution for using the objects with memory pool, the answer is generally -- "no". What you want is your classes, working with memory pool to take an allocator class. It allows a lot more flexibility and typically you don't just have one class, but many that would be put in memory pool, so you don't want to have a mass overload of all new/delete functions. Also, it's not unusual to have several allocation schemes (and therefore allocators), but you can overload new/delete only once.

Comment: Answering your question: how to prevent from calling a destructor in C++? This can be done only if you are going make use of placement new for allocation, in which case, you (as a programmer) must take the responsibility to call destructor manually ( like Doug said : p->~Foo::Foo(); ). That is the only instance in language when a programmer HAS to call destructor manually.

Answer (score 0):

7 years later it might be easy to appear clever, nevertheless let me write this.

Standard C++ ( 17 / 20) is very much [value semantics driven language](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics) , or as the Creator said: "New language".

So just please prefer values (and references where necessary) and use "smart" pointers if you really have to.
And above all forget about overloading new and/or delete. You know the drill :)